# How do I select TOP 5 PERCENT from each group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I have a sample table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(Category VARCHAR(100), Name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'John')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'John')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'John')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'John')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'John')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'John')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'Adam')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'Adam')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'Adam')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'Adam')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'Lisa')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'Lisa')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 'Bucky')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Lily')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Lily')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Lily')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Lily')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Lily')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Tom')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Tom')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Tom')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Tom')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Ross')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Ross')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 'Ross')

SELECT Category, Name, COUNT(Name) Total
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY Category, Name
ORDER BY Category, Total DESC

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Gives me the following:

```
A   John    6
A   Adam    4
A   Lisa    2
A   Bucky   1
B   Lily    5
B   Tom     4
B   Ross    3
```

Now, how do I select the `TOP 5 PERCENT` records from each category *assuming each category has more than 100 records (did not show in sample table here)*? For instance, in my actual table, it should remove the `John` record from `A` and `Lily` record from `B` as appropriate (again, I did not show the full table here) to get:

```
A   Adam    4
A   Lisa    2
A   Bucky   1
B   Tom     4
B   Ross    3
```

I have been trying to use `CTE`s and `PARTITION BY` clauses but cannot seem to achieve what I want. It removes the TOP 5 PERCENT from the overall result but not from each category. Any suggestions?

Comment: May help in a small way - If you have a count for a group, remember that 5 percent would be "row_num <= (5 * count) / 100"

Comment: @KierenJohnstone: +1 Thank you. I know I might have to use CROSS APPLY or something similar but still having some trouble. Will update if I figure it out.

Comment: What is the desired output then please? Remove top 5 percent percent is very little compared to a count of 6. One row (A, John) is 16%.

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373451/select-top-n-percent-by-year

Comment: @gbn: Sorry! I could not add 100 records to the sample table. I updated my question to have the assumption that I have more than 100 records in each category. I put the output I am expecting but of course this won't work on the sample table.

Comment: @Legend - Still not clear to me what you want. Please give desired results and explain how they are arrived at. Not sure at what point you want the `TOP 5%` applied.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Updated my question with an example output. I want the `TOP 5 PERCENT` to be applied **after** calculating the counts.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right, but it's going to be very hard to remove some rows but not others if they don't have unique fields. I.e. let's suppose there are 100 `A, John` records; you can only remove all or none of them, not the top 5%.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use a CTE (Common Table Expression) paired with the `NTILE` windowing function - this will slice up your data into as many slices as you need, e.g. in your case, into 20 slices (each 5%).

```
;WITH SlicedData AS
(
   SELECT Category, Name, COUNT(Name) Total,
            NTILE(20) OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY COUNT(Name) DESC) AS  'NTile'
   FROM #TEMP
   GROUP BY Category, Name
)
SELECT *
FROM SlicedData
WHERE NTile > 1
```

This basically groups your data by `Category,Name`, orders by something else (not sure if `COUNT(Name)` is really the thing you want here), and then slices it up into 20 pieces, each representing 5% of your data partition. The slice with `NTile = 1` is the top 5% slice - just ignore that when selecting from the CTE.

See:

- [MSDN docs on NTILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2005 ranking functions](http://SQL%20Server%202005%20ranking%20functions%20-%20RANK%28%29,%20DENSE_RANK%28%29,%20NTILE%28%29)
- [SQL SERVER – 2005 – Sample Example of RANKING Functions – ROW_NUMBER, RANK, DENSE_RANK, NTILE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/09/sql-server-2005-sample-example-of-ranking-functions-row_number-rank-dense_rank-ntile/)

for more info

Comment: This serves my purpose. Thanks a million. I fixed your post for some missing parts in the query to make it run out of the box.

Comment: @Legend I thought you wanted to remove records, not just select them?

Comment: @TimRogers: Sure. I just made an exclusion list using this query for the names that I wanted to remove. I will try to fix my question.

Answer (score 3):

```
select Category,name,CountTotal,RankSeq,(50*CountTotal)/100 from (
select Category,name,COUNT(*)
over (partition by Category,name ) as CountTotal,
ROW_NUMBER()
over (partition by Category,name order by Category) RankSeq from #TEMP
--group by Category,Name 
) temp
where RankSeq <= ((50*CountTotal)/100)
order by Category,Name,RankSeq
```

**Output:**

```
Category    name     CountTotal RankSeq     50*CountTotal)/100
A           Adam     4          1           2
A           Adam     4          2           2
A           John     6          1           3
A           John     6          2           3
A           John     6          3           3
A           Lisa     2          1           1
B           Lily     5          1           2
B           Lily     5          2           2
B           Ross     3          1           1
B           Tom      4          1           2
B           Tom      4          2           2
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH SlicedData AS
(
   SELECT Category, Name, COUNT(Name) Total,
            **PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY COUNT(Name) DESC) * 100** AS  'Percent'
   FROM #TEMP
   GROUP BY Category, Name
)
SELECT *
FROM SlicedData
WHERE Percent < 5
```

NTile will not work if number of records is less than your tile number.