# TSQL - 50:50 split of records in group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, sample

I am trying to find a way to split records for a test. I have a couple of columns that I need to consider like mailsegment and pack. I am wanting to get an even (or as close to) split at both levels and rolled up.

I have seen this solution ([How do I select TOP 5 PERCENT from each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579916/how-do-i-select-top-5-percent-from-each-group)) and applied it to my problem with reasonable success at the detailed level, however when I roll my segments up to a pack level it isn't even. This is due to mailsegments having an odd number of records in some cases. Is there a way that I can balance this out at a pack level (eg. only 2 packs) and still stratify my sample accurately across my mailsegment (200+ segments)?

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a stratified sample.  You can do this by using `row_number()` and taking the nth value:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by mailsegment, pack order by newid()) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum % 20 = 1;
```

EDIT:

The above should work, but it is actually better to sort the data without partitioning.

For an update:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by mailsegment, pack, newid()) as seqnum
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set myField = 'Test 1'
    where seqnum % 20 = 1;
```

This will work for additional test cells.

Comment: So if I need to update `table t` I could use `update t set myfield = 'Test 1' from (...`. Would that be correct? Also not to be difficult, could this be further applied on an even 3 or 4 way split?