# SQL server 2008, select students with highest grades from each class

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a db that looks like this

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| ID     | Class | grade |
+--------+-------+-------+
| 123    |   A   | 100   |
| 2      |   B   | 84    |
| 357    |   A   | 46    |
| 43     |   B   | 12    |
| 55677  |   B   | 78    |
| 63432  |   A   | 63    |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

obviously, I am dealing with much bigger db. 
more students, and more classes
wha I want to achieve is select two students with the highest grades from each class.

So, it should show:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| ID    | Class | Grade |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 123   | A     | 100   |
| 63432 | A     | 63    |
| 2     | B     | 84    |
| 55677 | B     | 78    |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

How do I achieve this thank you!

I tried this, but it gives me all rows

```
select id, class, max(grade)
from school
group by id, class
```

++++

There is another thing that I'd like to do with this db. 
How do I go about pulling top 10% students from each class? 
After I added a rank attribute,  I tried using 'having' after group by like this:

```
rank < count(distinct ID) * 0.05
```

Thank you!

Comment: What if there's a tie in second place? I.e. add (321, B, 78) to the sample table data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function with partition by clause.

```
;WITH CTE AS (

SELECT id, Class, Grade,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Class ORDER BY Grade DESC) as rnk
FROM tableName
)

SELECT id, Class, Grade
FROM CTE
WHERE rnk <=2
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` will not generate same rank for students with same grade.

Comment: Do you know a way to pull top 10% students from each class? thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579916/how-do-i-select-top-5-percent-from-each-group

Answer (score 1):

for this you need to use group by and having:

```
    select id,Class,Grade 
    from Student e 
    where Grade=(select max(Grade) 
    from Student w 
    group by w.Class having e.class=w.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, *[`DENSE_RANK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173825.aspx)* is better here than *[`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)*.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rank] = dense_rank() over(
        partition by [Class]
        order by [grade] desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select * from cte
where [rank] <= 2;
```

Comment: how did you line the database the way you did it? I always used a lot of spaces to line the numbers. How did you do + -- | this stuff? It looks a lot better, thank you for editing my question .

Comment: Do you know a way to pull top 10% students from each class? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
WITH result AS (

SELECT Id, Class, Grade,
       dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY Class ORDER BY Grade DESC) as DenseRank
FROM tableName
)

SELECT Id, Class, Grade
FROM result
WHERE DenseRank <=2
```

more than one student with same highest grade will also be considered.

Comment: Do you know a way to pull top 10% students from each class? thank you!